# The British cuisine 'is formed' by European and Asian food

Tags: word-choice

Do I use  **"to be formed"** correctly?

> The British cuisine  'is formed'  by European  and Asian food.

Can I use " be made of" also?

Comment: Food does not make or form cuisine; quite the contrary.

Comment: @StoneyB Should I use the word cuisine again? The British cuisine 'is formed' by European and Asian cuisine?

Comment: Do you wish to say that British cuisine was a product of external cuisines? Or do you rather wish to say that British cuisine 'produced itself', perhaps drawing upon those other cuisines, or influenced by them, or something of the sort? Enter into a dialogue with the language rather than just grabbing the first word that comes to hand.

Comment: Actually I just try to say "one thing is made by two or more things".British cuisine is just example I wanted to use.Another example could be " surprisingly this small machine was formed by more than 100 parts"

Comment: Ah! You want to say it was formed **from** small parts or **with** small parts. (Please don't ask which; no two people will agree on an answer!) The parts themselves do not play an active role, so a *by* phrase is inappropriate.

Comment: I might just add that British folks would probably be offended by your assertion that they have no "native " cuisine. British cuisine has indeed absorbed influences from many countries, as has the English language.

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated to your immediate question, but still good to know - your sentence should start with "British cuisine", not "**The** British cuisine". When we talk about things in general, the definite article is omitted:

- American culture has roots in many traditions. (not "**the** American culture")
- Classical music is still a source of inspiration today. (not **the** classical music)

There are a few exceptions to that rule, such as when talking about heavenly bodies like **the** Sun and **the** Moon. But in your case, you should get rid of "the".

As to the distinction between "formed by" and "formed from" - the former refers to the *method* or *process* responsible for forming, while the latter refers to the *constituents* or *materials* used to form things.

- Artificial diamonds are formed **by** applying high pressure to carbon.
- Artificial diamonds are formed **from** carbon.

I'm not sure whether it's common usage to say that cuisine is "formed" from different kinds of food. I'd say something like:

- British cuisine unites the cuisines of Europe and Asia.
- British cuisine has both European and Asian influences.
- Both European and Asian food are represented (or "can be found") in British cuisine.

Or, if you want to be really poetic, you could say:

- British cuisine is formed by the marriage of European and Asian food.

Comment: Thank you your answer and correcting me on articles.How about these sentences : " this city is formed from three main districts."  - " This cluster is formed from people different European countries and Asians"  - " This machine was formed from / made of about 100 parts." Do they sound ok?

Comment: 1) This city has/comprises three main districts. 2) "This cluster..." looks good. 3) This machine was made of about 100 parts. Look at the definition of "to form" here: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/form